# Fling using GestureDetector android

Tags: android

```
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(velocityX<-10.0f)
            {
                mCurrentStateLayout = mCurrentStateLayout == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                switchLayoutStateTo(mCurrentStateLayout);
            }
            return true;    
        }           
    });
```

What does the statement mCurrentStateLayout = mCurrentStateLayout == 0 ? 1 : 0; mean?

Comment: This is a Java syntax question, no relation to fling or GestureDetector. The title/tags should be edited to avoid future confusion when searching.

Answer (score 1):

```
mCurrentStateLayout = mCurrentStateLayout == 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

This is a [ternary](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018) operator in Java. It is essentially short hand for an if else statement.

If mCurrentStateLayout **is** equal to 0, the statement is true and mCurrentStateLayout is assigned the value of 1.

If mCurrentStateLayout is **not** equal to 0, the statement is false and mCurrentStateLayout is assigned the value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

To show it in code. This is analog of the code you pasted here:

```
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(velocityX<-10.0f)
            {
                if (mCurrentStateLayout == 0) {
                    mCurrentStateLayout = 1;
                } else {
                    mCurrentStateLayout = 0;
                }
                switchLayoutStateTo(mCurrentStateLayout);
            }
            return true;    
        }           
    });
```